How to merge two pages from a pdf file in Python such that they are one next to the other?
I'm basically trying to grab two pages and put them one next to the other using python since I want to print a booklet on some A4 pages. The issue I'm finding is that the translation of the page in the right keeps making the page disappear (I limited the translation to half the width of the page, such that the disappearance can be seen clearly when running the code).
I would appreciate any help!
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter, PdfReader, PageObject, Transformation

def process_pdf(input_pdf_path, output_pdf_path):
    # Open the input PDF file
    pdf_reader = PdfReader(input_pdf_path)
    pdf_writer = PdfWriter()

    num_pages = len(pdf_reader.pages)
    page1 = pdf_reader.pages[0]
    page2 = pdf_reader.pages[1]

    merged_page = merge_pages(page1, page2)
    pdf_writer.add_page(merged_page)

    with open(output_pdf_path, 'wb') as output_pdf_file:
        pdf_writer.write(output_pdf_file)

def merge_pages(page_left, page_right):
    # Get the dimensions of the pages
    page_width = page_left.mediabox.width
    page_height = page_left.mediabox.height
    
    # Create a new blank page with double width
    merged_page = PageObject.create_blank_page(width=page_width*2, height=page_height)

    # Merge the left page on the left side of the new page
    merged_page.merge_page(page_left)

    # Apply translation transformation to the right page
    translation = Transformation().translate(tx=page_width/2, ty=0)
    page_right.add_transformation(translation)

    # Merge the right page on the right side of the new page
    merged_page.merge_page(page_right,expand=True)

    return merged_page

# Test
input_pdf = 'input.pdf'  # Path to the input PDF file
output_pdf = 'output.pdf'  # Path to the output PDF file
process_pdf(input_pdf, output_pdf)

You can try this with any pdf with at least 2 pages and you will see what the problem is.

Here is an example how easy this is with PyMuPDF. Note: I am a maintainer and the original creator of PyMuPDF.

The following modification solves the problem, so anyone with the same problem can use it:
# Function to merge two pages side by side
def merge_pages(page_left, page_right):
    # Get the dimensions of the pages
    page_width = page_left.mediabox.width
    page_height = page_left.mediabox.height
    # Create a new blank page with double width
    merged_page = PageObject\
            .create_blank_page(width=page_width*2, height=page_height)
    # Merge the right page to the new page
    merged_page.merge_page(page_right)
    # Add a translation of 1 width to the right of all contents of merge_page
    merged_page.add_transformation(Transformation()\
                                  .translate(tx=page_width,ty=0))
    # Merge the left page on the left side of the new page
    merged_page.merge_page(page_left)
    # The new page is ready
    return merged_page

As you can see, you need to merge the wide page with the right page first, apply a translation to the contents of the wide page and THEN merge the left page.
Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.
